# Notification, NotificationManager, and StatusBar Messages for Android

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, notificationmanager

1. In this code snippet, what Activity class do I use?  The one where the code is written?  Is this statusbar message going somewhere?

   `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);`
2. Does this method act immediately or it's done later?

   `NotificationManager.notify();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this code snippet, what Activity class do I use?

How should we know? We are not mind readers, and you have given us one line out of a much larger example somewhere.

Taking a completely random guess, that is probably the activity that should be opened when the user taps on the notification entry.

> Does this method act immediately or it's done later?

The call is asynchronous, but it should be displayed almost immediately.

Comment: Hi, I think you are a mind reader.  I didn't realize that clicking on the notification message was supposed to start some activity (I thought notifications just displayed a message).  So, yeah that is exactly what I want.